# Stable numerical integration of a PDE with a bounded variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, constraints

My colleagues and I are trying to numerically integrate a physics-based PDE (phase field model of diffusive phase separation) of the form
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left [ a(\phi) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + b(\phi) \frac{\partial^{3} \phi}{\partial x^{3}} \right ]
\tag{1}
$$
where 
$$
a(\phi) = (1 - \phi)/N + \phi - 2 \chi \phi (1-\phi),
$$ 
$$
b(\phi) = \kappa \phi (1-\phi),
$$ and $\chi$, $\kappa$ and $N$ are real positive numbers.

There are several challenges to numerically integrating this system (e.g. stiffness), and we have typically used a pseudo-spectral method for the spatial derivatives and a semi-implicit, variable step-size Euler stepping scheme for the time integration (more details can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999103002808) and [here](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2017/sm/c6sm02839j)).

However, some of our most persistent challenges relate to the fact that there are physical bounds that constrain $\phi \in [0, 1]$. We find that if the equation is integrated with sufficient accuracy (i.e. if we use a sufficiently small time step), this is not a problem. However, at large values of $N$ and $\chi$ it becomes very difficult to reach the necessary accuracy.

Aside from simply increasing the accuracy of our time integration (e.g. smaller time step, higher order method, exponential time differencing) are there methods that we can use to stabilize our integration and keep $\phi$ between 0 and 1?

Comment: You could try to put: $$\phi = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-u)}$$ so that the boundary values for $\phi$ are moved to minus and plus infinity.

Comment: @CountIblis Thank you for the suggestion. We have considered this approach, but it is reasonably difficult to implement. The transformation introduces a term on the LHS of Eq.~1 from the chain rule: $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \frac{d \phi}{d u}$. This makes it difficult (impossible?) to use our semi-implicit pseudo-spectral scheme that relies on a Fourier transform that commutes with the time derivative. The approach also adds extra terms from the chain rule in the spatial derivatives, which gets very messy in our full multivariate version of this model.

Comment: You can try to consider an implicit Runge-Kutta method for the time integration. Except high order accuracy you get excellent stability properties (which allow larger time steps). I have personally made a good experience with five-stage L-stable diagonally implicit Runge-Kutta method of 5th order on a PDE system where many standard integrators had failed. I can provide the Butcher array of this particular method, if you like. Implementation of the implicit R.-K. is easy, because fixed point iteration is fully sufficient to use (no Newton method is necessary).